# vl_sift() not working in Octave?

Tags: octave, vlfeat

I installed the `vlfeat` library using `apt-get install octave-vlfeat`. For some reason, the SIFT function does not work, and says "vl_sift() undefined". This is at the same time when functions like `vl_hog()` and `vl_kmeans()` do work perfectly fine.

No results for `which vl_sift`.

Has anyone else faced similar issues? Is there some additional dependency?

Octave 3.8.1

Comment: Have you run vl_setup before?

Comment: @Andy no, `vl_setup` is undefined too. And yet I was able to use the functions I mentioned.

Comment: Did you load it with "pkg load vlfeat"? Does "pkg list" show an * after your package?

Comment: `pkg load vlfeat` says it is not installed, and it doesn't show up in `pkg list` at all. Although, trying to install it via `apt-get install` tells me it's already the newest version. What am I missing here!?